# Order terms by creation date

Tags: terms, order

How can I add the order by date created to this function?

```
if ( !isset( $gmw['search_results']['custom_taxes'] ) )
    return;

$taxonomies = apply_filters( 
    'gmw_pt_results_taxonomies', 
    get_object_taxonomies( $post->post_type, 'names' ), 
    $gmw, 
    $post 
);

$output ='';

foreach ( $taxonomies as $tax ) {

    $terms = get_the_terms( $post->ID, $tax );

    if ( $terms && !is_wp_error( $terms ) ) {

        $termsArray = array();
        $the_tax = get_taxonomy( $tax );

        foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
            $termsArray[] = $term->name;
        }
```

Comment: Where do you have the terms' creation date from? It's not stored by default as far as I remember.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to achieve that, then you need to add  `creation_date` for each taxonomy, hooked with 'create_category' (or create_YOURTAXONOMYNAME) function.

lets say,for example, you add a new category :

```
add_action( "create_category", 'my_func123', 10, 2 ); 
function my_func123( $term_id, $tt_id){
    update_option('my_taxnm_date_'.$term_id, time());
}
```

then later, anytime, you will be able to get the creation date for each taxonomy id:

```
foreach ( $terms as $term ) {
   $termsArray[]['Name'] = $term->name;
   $termsArray[]['Date'] = get_option('my_taxnm_date_'.  $term->term_id) ;
}
```

now, you just have to sort the array, like: `ksort($termsArray[]);` and then you will have sorted array.